# Vectorized way of finding position of one column value in another in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Basically the following code returns the position of a character in column 'a' in another string (in this case '}JKLMNOPQR'). In this example, column 'b' has the same value in all rows, but it could have different values.

Is there a vectorized way to do this?

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['L', '}', 'P']})
frame['b']='}JKLMNOPQR'
frame['c'] = frame.apply(lambda row: row.b.find(row.a), axis=1)
frame

   a        b         c
0  L    }JKLMNOPQR    3 
1  }    }JKLMNOPQR    0 
2  P    }JKLMNOPQR    7
```

Answer (score 3):

Not vectorized but a faster solution using `zip`:

```
lframe1 = pd.concat([frame]*1000)
lframe2 = pd.concat([frame]*1000)

%timeit lframe1['c'] = lframe1.apply(lambda row: row.b.find(row.a), axis=1)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 77.7 ms per loop

%timeit lframe2['c'] = [b.find(a) for a, b in zip(lframe2.a, lframe2.b)]
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop

lframe1.c.eq(lframe2.c).all()
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` from `np.core.defchararray`

```
np.core.defchararray.find(frame.b.values.astype(str), frame.a)

array([3, 0, 7])
```

---

Wrap this up with `assign`

```
frame.assign(c=np.core.defchararray.find(frame.b.values.astype(str), frame.a))

   a           b  c
0  L  }JKLMNOPQR  3
1  }  }JKLMNOPQR  0
2  P  }JKLMNOPQR  7
```

---

**Timing**
Hard to beat @Psidom's `zip`
*Code Below*

[image]

```
pir1 = lambda d: d.assign(c=np.core.defchararray.find(d.b.values.astype(str), d.a.values.astype(str)))
pir2 = lambda d: d.assign(c=(np.array([list(x) for x in d.b.values.tolist()]) == d.a.values[:, None]).argmax(1))
psi = lambda d: d.assign(c=[b.find(a) for a, b in zip(d.a, d.b)])
jso = lambda d: d.assign(c=d.apply(lambda row: row.b.find(row.a), axis=1))

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000]),
    columns='pir1 pir2 psi jso'.split()
)

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([frame] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))

results.plot(loglog=True)
```